# How to change the default Firebase Auth actions domain to my custom domain?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

How to change the default Firebase Auth actions domain to my custom domain? I want to change it from `reply@project-name.firebaseapp.com` to `reply@app.example.com` but with another verification method for the domain rather than adding `TXT` & `CName` records to my DNS configuration.

I want something simple as adding a `.txt` file with the other project files and uploading it to the hosting. That's all because my current hosting doesn't support the `TXT` & `CName` records.

By the default Firebase Auth actions, I mean the password reset email, email verification, email address change, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a follow up to our discussion in the comments,

Since your project is being hosted on a Netlify subdomain, I found the following in [their documentation:](https://docs.netlify.com/domains-https/netlify-dns/dns-records/#add-a-new-record)

> ### To add a new DNS record:
>
> 1. Go to the **Domains** tab for your team.
> 2. Select the domain you want to edit.
> 3. At the bottom of the **DNS records** panel, select **Add new record**.
> 4. Choose the type of record to create from the menu and fill in the remaining options. The fields you need to fill out will depend on the
>    type of record you select.
> 5. Select **Save** to create the record and make the changes live. Remember, it may take up to a few hours for record changes to
>    propagate.
>
> Note that you can host records for other services, such as your mail
> provider or your backend API, with us as long as you host at least one
> website with us that uses the domain.

If this isn't allowed, I would suggest getting a custom domain, and pointing both Firebase and Netlify to it. It's more professional than a hosted subdomain, and it'll stay yours forever. Doing a quick search, I found plenty of interesting and currently available domains relating to `msk-apps`.